# How to record an iPad screencast

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator

How do you record an iPad screencast at full scale?

I have an iMac with maximum resolution 1680x1050 and the simulator doesn't fit the screen in portrait orientation. It does fit in landscape orientation.

Reducing the scale to 50% is not an option because the end result is too small. If the scale could be reduced slightly it would be fine, but not 50%.

Is it possible to put the simulator in landscape orientation and still keep the app in portrait mode? Then I could simply rotate the resulting video to get a portrait screencast.

Comment: I'm not sure if SU ever decided whether or not they like iPad questions (last I heard they were [leaning towards yes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36202/will-ipad-be-acceptable-subject-matter-for-super-user)), so I guess I'll vote for migration and find out

Comment: I don't think this belongs to SU. Recording the screencast is part of our development and testing process.

Comment: I don't think that really matters; recording as part of a development process isn't any different than recording for other reasons

Comment: It is if the question is useful for iPad developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off autorotation for the viewcontrollers you want to show (probably all):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
     return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

You could wrap this up in #if ... #endif and make a special screencast build with a preprocessor SCREENCAST constant defined, so that you can easily turn this on and off.

Look out for the mouse pointer if you capture that as well, as the standard arrow will be rotated in your final movie.

Comment: Doesn't work in all cases, but it was good enough for what I needed to do. Thanks!